# problemas com emulador

Tags: android-studio

estou tentando programar no Android Studio, mas não estou conseguindo fazer o emulador funcionar, já tentei usar me telefone, mas o choose device não reconhece, mas em outros computadores o meu telefone é reconhecido e é utilizado, o que estou fazendo errado?

Comment: Provavelmente seu computador não está reconhecendo seu aparelho com a `Depuração USB`, você já fez a autorização?

Comment: Já ativei, porém descobri que está faltando os drives adb no meu PC, vou baixar pra ver se funciona

Comment: Eu sempre uso esse aqui: http://www.xda-developers.com/lightweight-adb-and-fastboot-installer/

Answer (score 0):

Verifique se o seu SO é x64, pois a google está meio que forçando os desenvolvedores utilizar esta arquitetura para desenvolver apps  Android. Até um tempo atrás, eu rodava o avd pelo terminal usando este comando: emulator -avd 'nome-avd' (sem aspas) --force-32bits